# Pause and Resume a Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I have a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
foreach (var line in theCP4UnknownList.Distinct())
{
    var splitUnknowns = line.Split(' ');
    KTS_Save saveForm = new KTS_Save(splitUnknowns[0], splitUnknowns[1], splitUnknowns[3], splitUnknowns[4], openFile.FileName);

    saveForm.Show();
    saveForm.Activate();
    //This is where I would like to add a check to see if a button is clicked, if true continue the foreach loop, else wait for the button to be clicked.
}
```

This `KTS_Save` form has 4 textbox fields which will be automatically filled every time (as well as other blank ones that need to be filled by the user) the foreach loop starts. However, I only want one new form to be open at a time, thus the program needs to wait for the user to click a "Save" button before the next `KTS_Save` form is opened.... The save button will save the current data in the form to a text file.

Is there any possible way to pause the foreach loop and wait for a button to be clicked? How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: C# Forms in VS. winforms.

Comment: Just curious, but you are planning on putting this in a separate thread, right?  This thread is going to hang while the loop waits.

Comment: @MGZero: Actually I was not, Fischermaen has answered my question below. I can't believe what an easy fix it was. lol

Comment: Can I ask why the -1? Curious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your code to that:

```
foreach (var line in theCP4UnknownList.Distinct()) 
{ 
    var splitUnknowns = line.Split(' '); 
    KTS_Save saveForm = new KTS_Save(splitUnknowns[0], splitUnknowns[1], splitUnknowns[3], splitUnknowns[4], openFile.FileName); 

    saveForm.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `saveForm.ShowDialog()` instead of `saveForm.Show()`